# Merge array of objects based on overall key of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have this array of objects

```
var worksSummaryDetailsArr = [
  {
    year: 2020,
    worksSummaryDetailsObj: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    year: 2021,
    worksSummaryDetailsObj: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    worksSummaryDetailsObj: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    year: 2021,
    worksSummaryDetailsObj: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    worksSummaryDetailsObj: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

I want to merge it into

```
  {
    year: 2020,
    worksSummaryDetailsObj: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    year: 2021,
    worksSummaryDetailsObj: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    year: 2022,
    worksSummaryDetailsObj: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
```

I have tried using the set function and mapping with the same year, and the output was the same years were merged correctly but the worksSummaryDetailsObj contains wrong data

here is my code

```
const r = [...new Set(worksSummaryDetailsArr.map((i) => i.year))].map((i) => ({
      year: i,
      worksSummaryDetailsObj: [...new Set(worksSummaryDetailsArr.filter(({ year: c }) => c === i))],
}));

console.log(r);
```

Comment: I linked some options but this has been asked many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple reduce and array merge could achieve what you want

```
Object.values(
  worksSummaryDetailsArr.reduce((acc, arr) => {
    if (!acc[arr.year]) {
      acc[arr.year] = arr;
    } else {
      acc[arr.year] = {
        ...acc[arr.year],
        worksSummaryDetailsObj: [
          ...acc[arr.year].worksSummaryDetailsObj,
          ...arr.worksSummaryDetailsObj,
        ],
      };
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
```